# Ios crash "could not execute support code to read Objective-C" on ios 12.4.2 not on 12.0.1

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image, ciimage

This method returns a qr code image of a string. It works correctly on Ios 12.0.1 (iphone SE) but it crash on 12.4.2 (iphone 6). The method crash when i try to assign the resultant `UIImage` to an `UIImageView`, the resultant `UIImage` is not nil.

```
-(UIImage*)get_QR_image :(NSString*)qrString :(UIColor*)ForeGroundCol :(UIColor*)BackGroundCol{

    NSData *stringData = [qrString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    CIFilter *qrFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
    [qrFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
    [qrFilter setValue:@"H" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];


    CIImage *qrImage = qrFilter.outputImage;
    float scaleX = 320;
    float scaleY = 320;


    CIColor *iForegroundColor = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:[ForeGroundCol CGColor]];
    CIColor *iBackgroundColor = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:[BackGroundCol CGColor]];

    CIFilter * filterColor = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor" keysAndValues:@"inputImage", qrImage, @"inputColor0", iForegroundColor, @"inputColor1", iBackgroundColor, nil];

    CIImage *filtered_image = [filterColor valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

    filtered_image = [filtered_image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY)];

    UIImage *result_image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:filtered_image
                                                 scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale
                                           orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];


    return result_image;
}
```

the line involved in crash is:

```
filtered_image = [filtered_image imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY)];
```

it generates this log:

```
warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
```

There's something in my method that works only on 12.0.1 ? Or maybe something wrong ? How i can investigate more to solve that crash ?

EDIT

[image]

in red i have:

```
MyQrCodeImageViewBig.image=qrimage;
```

with messagge:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1a83e146c)
```

Comment: Could you maybe post the crash message itself?

Comment: i have added more info about the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a lot of problems resulting from the `[UIImage imageWithCIImage:]` initializer. The main problem being that a `CIImage` does not actually contain any bitmap data. It needs to be rendered by a `CIContext` first. So the target you assign the `UIImage` to needs to *know* that it is backed by a `CIImage` that still needs rendering. Usually `UIImageView` handles this well, but I wouldn't trust it too much.

What you can do instead is to render the image yourself into a bitmap (`CGImage`) and initialize the `UIImage` with that instead. You need a `CIContext` for that, which I recommend you create somewhere outside this method *once* and re-use it every time you need to render an image (it's an expensive object):

```
self.context = [CIContext context];
```

Then in your method, you render the image like this:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [self.context createCGImage:filtered_image fromRect:[filtered_image extent]];
UIImage* result_image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```